# Create table error with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to create a table in MySQL:

```
mysql> create table order ( ID varchar(30) not null,
    -> Cname varchar(100) not null,
    -> name varchar(30),
    -> Type varchar(30), 
    -> primary key(ID, Cname));
```

but an error occured:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'order ( ID varchar(30) not null, Cname
>   varchar(100) not null, name varchar(30), ' at line 1

I have checked for thousand time and I still find no error here.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: My point is you might get much more help if you don't use vague words. But you got your problem solved, so there you go

Comment: @Chisko Sorry for this, I truly didn't know where the rub was before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is because of the table name **order**. 
There is an **order by**  reserved word. Change the table name and it will work fine.

If you want `order` as table name use back ticks around the table name. It will workfine

Comment: My bad. I have only checked keyword conflict for columns. Thank you!